# How can I concatenate a string and variable into the name of another variable in React?

Tags: reactjs, variables, concatenation, src, template-literals

I am importing images and naming them `img1`, `img2`, `img3` etc. I want to be able to increase the number on the name when I click a button, but when I concatenate or use template literals it returns a string.

Here for clarity:

```
import img1 from 'img1.jpg'
import img2 from 'img2.jpg'
import img3 from 'img3.jpg'

const [ num, setNum ] = useState(1)

function handleNextClick() {
    setNum(num + 1)
}
```

This is where my problem is:

```
<img src={ 'img' + num} alt="" />
```

It returns as:

```
<img src='img1' alt="" />
```

I want:

```
<img src={img1} alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store your images in a reference array, and pull from there:

```
import img1 from 'img1.jpg'
import img2 from 'img2.jpg'
import img3 from 'img3.jpg'

const images = [img1, img2, img3]
```

Then you can reference by index:

```
<img src={images[num - 1]} alt="" />
```

Note the - 1 to the num in order to use the zero index array.

Comment: This worked just fine...

Comment: Cool :) feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello in javascript you can do this by simply destructuring your values.
and you can always access them by their index array indices usually start at 0

```
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

so if you want to get the first value you do

```
x[0];
```

check out this page from MDN Web Docs to learn about destructuring assignments
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

and this on arrays
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array